# Exclude a @Configuration component in Application for integration test in ApplicationTest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, spring-boot-test

I'm trying to implement my integration test. And my Application is implement like the following:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = ["com.lib"])
class Application
```

in the com.lib, there's a @Configuration class call `SystemConfig` that have a @Bean marked as @Primary that I want to override with `MyConfig` class, so I implement my ApplicationTest is implement as following:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [Application::class, MyConfig::class])
class ApplicationTest
```

I have been trying to use all the way this link suggested https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-exclude-auto-configuration-test
for example adding

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=SystemConfig.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [Application::class, MyConfig::class])
class ApplicationTest
```

but nothing worked so far. And if I mark the @Bean in `MyConfig` as @Primary, then it will have exception that there's multiple @Primary bean.

Thinking about using @Profile, but the SystemConfig is from external lib so I can not modify it.

Answer (score 0):

I think using `@Profile` is a nice option, it should be possible to solve this using profiles even with third-party library.

Try this:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class ApplicationTest {
    // your integration test
}
```

create your custom configuration for test

```
@Configuration
@Profile("test")
public class MyConfig {
    @Bean(name = "nameOfTheExternalBean")
    @Primary
    public YourBean yourBean() {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay I tried to use Profile, it's turned out that I got different problem, so in order to run, I just need to name the Bean exactly the same with the Bean in the external library and it is resolved. If you could please update your answer a bit and I will mark this as answered :D

Comment: If I get it correctly, it runs an overriding mechanism using the same bean name from the external library. 
When two beans have the same name, Spring will use the one that is loaded last. In your case, it should be MyConfig, but this is my assumption since I never tried it.

Comment: ah I've just checked again, still not work :( the external bean still got created no matter what I do

Comment: How do you know that this external bean corresponds to an external library since your bean `@Bean(name = "nameOfTheExternalBean")` has the same name?
Double-check that test profile actually loaded.

Comment: Try to add log to the bean and investigate. 
`log.info("My overridden config");`

Comment: yeah, already did it, and my overriden primary bean never get called :( other bean defined in Myconfig still got called, it’s just that specific Bean that share with that external library not get called

Comment: Try this: `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true`
Read this:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-definition-override-exception#4-beans-coming-from-3rd-party-libraries

I know you don't have any exceptions, but it is worth reading.